# How to pass file.ByChunk in dlang?

Tags: d, dmd

I'm newbie in D.

I have following code:

```
auto file = File("test.txt", "r");
scope(exit) file.close();

foreach (letter; getTextKernel(file.byChunk(8192))) {
    writeln(letter);
}
```

and my getTextKernel looks like:

```
string[] getTextKernel(InputRange!ubyte[] text) pure { ... }
```

I receive error:
getTextKernel (InputRange!ubyte[] text) is not callable using argument types (ByChunk)

documentation about byChunk : `Returns an input range set up to read from the file handle a chunk at a time.`

UPDATE: WHOLE PROGRAM

```
import std.stdio;

string[] getTextKernel(R)(R text) pure {
    return ["aa", "bbb", "ccc"];
}

void main() {
    writeln("Hello master dmitry!");

    auto file = File("test.txt", "r");
    scope(exit) file.close();

    // StubdGenetics genetic;
    foreach (letter; getTextKernel(file.byChunk(8192))) {
        writeln(letter);
    }
}
```

error: pure function 'app.getTextKernel!(ByChunk).getTextKernel' cannot call impure destructor 'std.stdio.File.ByChunk.~this'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is to make `getTextKernel` accept a template argument.

```
string[] getTextKernel(R)(R text) pure   { ... }
```

Because ranges are lazy in D they are often custom, one-off types. `InputRange` is almost never used in my experience. There are reasons to use it but it's slower (using runtime dispatch instead of compile time) and just generally not needed.

Comment: note that you may want to constrain `R` with `isInputRange!R` and `is(ElementType!R : ubyte[])` (both are provided by [std.range](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range_primitives.html#.isInputRange))

Comment: Thx, but now I have trouble with `pure` modifier. see my UPDATE

Comment: the bychunk thing isn't pure.. not much you can do about that except not use the pure or pass the chunck itself instead of the range